# Can I import presentation details via the Sitecore Data Exchange Framework

Tags: data-exchange-framework

I have seen the **Sitecore Data Exchange Framework** documentation and it explains very well how to use and implement the tool. It allows you to import data from third party system to sitecore.

My question is, does the Sitecore Data Exchange Framework allows to import presentations also? I know presentation on an item is stored as xml in the Renderings Fields but can I use the Sitecore Data Exchange to import this also?

Note that I have not implement any code right now since I am still in the analysis phase.

**EDIT 1**

Since the imported content will already be known, for example, the contents to be imported are Articles, I will already know what presentation details needs to be setup on the item. Then we will update the excel file accordingly to have a field for the presentation since some Articles presentation may be slightly different from other Articles. This is why I wanted to know if the rendering field can be modified by the Data Exchange as this field is a Sitecore Standard Field.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As the presentation details are stored in fields I wouldn't see why you couldn't use the Sitecore Data Exchange Framework to overwrite them.
You'll have to create the right mapping to the field. Info about the mapping can be found here: http://integrationsdn.sitecore.net/DataExchangeFramework/v1.1/getting-started/mapping/index.html

But I really doubt that it is a good idea. Can you explain more what the purpose of your import is?
You'll have presentation details in a 3rd party system?

Comment: I have updated the question